# Изменение текста в постраничной навигации views drupal 7

Tags: drupal, views

Здравствуйте, есть проблема в кастомизации постраничной навигации модуля views Drupal 7, нужно вставить делитель "1/34" вместо "1 of 34", кто уже такое делал?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределите [theme_views_mini_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/theme_views_mini_pager/7.x-3.x) в своем шаблоне.
Замените строку:

```
'data' => t('@current of @max', array('@current' => $pager_current, '@max' => $pager_max)),
```

на:

```
'data' => t('@current/@max', array('@current' => $pager_current, '@max' => $pager_max)),
```

Comment: Ура, заработало!) спасибо большое)